# equals versus memory comparision issue

Tags: java

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Long l = 500L;
  Long l1 = 500L;
  System.out.println(l == l1);
  User u = new User();
  u.setL(500L);
  User u1 = new User();
  u1.setL(500L);
  System.out.println(u.getL() == u1.getL());
}
```

The output of the above program comes as **false,true**. Why it was making difference output.

```java
public class User {

    private long l;

    public long getL() {
        return l;
    }

    public void setL(long l) {
        this.l = l;
    }

}
```

The Above definition is for user class

Comment: There is nothing called as stringpool or intrger pool for L.

Comment: What's the return type of `User.getL()`? Is it primitive `long`?

Comment: @ivan yeah its a primitive long only

Answer (score 6):

`Long` is not a primitive data type but a class to wrap the `long` into an object.
So you cannot compare those 2 objects using `==` operator, it will always return false.
You need to use `equals()`.

Comment: @user3309305 Yes, you went on a conception problem of *Java*, the == operator working conveniently for primitives but not for objects. In 99% of cases, the programmer would like to use `==` to compare objects and not their pointers. And it's what is done in almost all languages.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan Not a knowledgeable java programmer. Objects use .equals, primitive types use ==. Yes, I feel that wasn't the best decision by the language-designers, but it's one I follow because this is how the language works.

Comment: A really knowledgeable programmer who is not familiar with Java would know NOT to assume that all programming languages behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Long` is a wrapper class `==` compares references like if two variable point to the exactly same object (same location in memory). To compare internals of the objects you need to use `equals()`. But if `User.gerL()` returns primitive `long` that is another story. For primitive types `==` compares internal values stored in those primitives. That is why second comparison returns true.